# What is the area of Psychology called that focuses on interaction and emotions?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, communication

Quickly to my background, I did communications studies for my bachelors and I am currently finishing my Psychology master.

In short, I should know what i am about to ask, but I don't.

When a person say something a specific was, for example:
Give me that pen!

the other person will feel a specific way because of it. Maybe some memories/experiences/traumas are activated/subconsciously recalled. Flight/Freeze or Fight may be executed and so on.

And finally a response is given. Which off course depends on a whole host of parameters (personal relation, status, current feelings or maybe even physical illness at the time etc.)

This interaction off course is communication, but it seems like there should be a science or an area of study that focuses specifically on the emotional/behavioral side of communications and at least tries to create a framework for this extremely complex phenomenon.

Communication as a field of science kind of does that, but not to a deep degree (at least i never stumbled across it) and kind of a psychological lens is needed on it as well in my opinion.

So far i am unable to call this area of science by any specific name, psychology and communication are both way to broad and don't really describe this, so what is it called then? Are there books on it? Am I a moron?

I know, a basic question, but neither google nor ChatGPT could answer me, maybe you can ^^

Answer (score 1):

I studied communication psychology in college. Maybe that's what you're looking for? You can use this reference as a start: APA Handbook of Interpersonal Communication, https://www.apa.org/pubs/books/4317224

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the study of human interactions are more the domain of "[sociology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology)" than of psychology, but the field of psychology specifically dealing with emotions is called "[Emotional Psychology](https://online.uwa.edu/news/emotional-psychology/)", of which the emotions in reaction of some interactions would be a minor subset, which I guess is not large enough to be a field in itself.

You might try searching for keywords such as "Emotions in the workplace" (which yields a corresponding [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotions_in_the_workplace) entirely dedicated to the topic!) to find results dealing with emotions and social interactions; or more generally keywords such as "social interactions and emotions" which leads to pages such as "[The Emotions of Social Interaction](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/anger-in-the-age-entitlement/201702/the-emotions-social-interaction)" and "[Studies in Emotion and Social Interaction](https://www.cambridge.org/core/series/studies-in-emotion-and-social-interaction/5477CB2D67EA76201FCD1E3F2DCD6F24)", each with various references more or less related to both emotions and social exchanges.

Finally, if you are doing a Master in Psychology, I would strongly suggest trusting your professors and not being afraid to ask them for advice and help: you are still a (Master) student, they are professor, if you ask respectfully they will be happy to help, it is part of the job of being a professor!

I hope it helps!